# show questions one at a time in quiz website in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have done a quiz website which shows a question and 4 options with radio button. the questions are fetched from database.  but all questions are showing up all at a time. i want to show one question at a time when the user clicks the option. soon after he clicks the option the current question should fade and show the next question. i have tried many ways using javascript and all but nothing is working. can anyone help me. here is my html code

```html
<div class="services">
<div class="container">

 <?php $response=mysql_query("select * from questions");?>
 <form method='post' id='quiz_form'>
<?php while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){ ?>
<div id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class='question'> <!--check the class for plurals if error occurs-->
<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><?php echo $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'];?></h2>


<div class='align'>
<input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer1'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans2_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer2'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans3_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer3'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer4'];?></label>
<input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id='next<?php echo $result['id'];?>' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/>
</div>

<?php }?>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Q1 -> Q2 -> Q3 or can it be  mixed like Q1->Q3->Q2?

Comment: anything is not a problem. i need it to appear one at a time and get the next question when clicking the radio button or submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've made an example of how you can realize this solution. You will need 3 files.

1) Download jquery library and put it in site root folder, in this example I use jquery-3.3.1.min.js

2) Create file index.php with this content

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="services">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click','#next', function(){
            var curr_id = $(this).data('nextQuestion');
            var answer1 = $('#radio1').is(':checked'); 
            var answer2 = $('#radio2').is(':checked'); 
            var answer3 = $('#radio3').is(':checked'); 
            var answer4 = $('#radio4').is(':checked');
            getQuestion(curr_id, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
    });

    function getQuestion(curr_id, answer1=false, answer2=false, answer3=false, answer4=false){
        $.post("ajax.php",
        {
            next_id: parseInt(curr_id)+1,
            answer1: answer1, 
            answer2: answer2, 
            answer3: answer3, 
            answer4: answer4,
        },
        function(data, status){
            $('#container').html(data);
        });
    }

    getQuestion(-1);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2) Create ajax.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz"); // change here to your data
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Check the number of all questions, if next_id is more than last question, back to first or whatever you want;
$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from questions");
$number_of_all_questions = mysqli_num_rows($response);

if($number_of_all_questions <= $_POST['next_id']){
    $_POST['next_id'] = 0;
}

// query next question

$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from questions WHERE id =(select min(id) from questions where id > {$_POST['next_id']})");
?>

<?php while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

    <div id="question_<?= $result['id'] ?>" class='question'> <!--check the class for plurals if error occurs-->
        <h2><?= $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'] ?></h2>
        <div class='align'>
            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1' name='1'>
            <label id='ans1' for='1'><?= $result['answer1'] ?></label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2' name='2'>
            <label id='ans2' for='2'><?= $result['answer2'] ?></label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3' name='3'>
            <label id='ans3' for='3'><?= $result['answer3'] ?></label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4' name='4'>
            <label id='ans4' for='4'><?= $result['answer4'] ?></label>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>" id='next' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/>
    </div>
<?php }?>
<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: Have you changed $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
with your data?

Comment: yes. this is my data $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quiz");

Comment: ok, check `$_POST['next_id'] ` with code `print_f($_POST['next_id'] );exit;` in ajax.php and be sure that row with this `id` is present in base. I also use xampp and everithing works

Comment: should i remove my form in the "container div"(look at my source code in question). and leave it blank as you did in ur source code

Comment: you should do all like in the example. Your button should look like this.
`<input type="button" data-next-question="<?= $_POST['next_id'] ?>" id='next' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/>`. You do not need to add question id to button.In `data-next-question` you will keep current question id

Comment: i have done all as you said. used print_f($_POST['next_id'] );exit;. but still is blank

Comment: Yes you should remove form. Just forget about YOUR code for a minute and create new site folder to test my code, create index.php and ajax.php and put jquery library as I described above. Add your db data and test. I've made example from your code

Comment: can you just check the ajax.php of urs. i think there is some syntax error

Comment: Ok, I changed last code, to new one (tested on my localsite, everything works), try now. This should work. if not you do something wrong.

Comment: i have done excatly as you said. still not working. can you share me ur email id

Comment: sure - enbachtov@gmail.com, send me your source files and I'll correct it to you. Also send me your db

Answer (score 1):

that is because you're using `select * from questions`, this will fetch everything in the questions database, what you would be doing is requesting one question at a time `select * from questions LIMIT 0, 1 // index_from, amount`, And then next time increase your limit with one `LIMIT 1, 1`

Comment: thanks ive got given the code and got one question at a time. how can i move to the 2nd question?

Comment: @SawBuz keep track of how many questions were displayed and use that with LIMIT

Comment: @aayushi-kambariya 's answer has the JS you need. If it still does not work, then put your JavaScript code here and people wll be able to help you in fixing your code.

Answer (score 1):

A general and efficient approach to achieve this by **loading the question in UI one at a time,** when your desired event fired in UI.
Lets elaborate the strategy here

**Step 1:** there will be js function call to load the desired question.
    the desired or existing question id will be argument to this js
    function.

**Step 2** the js function will have a ajax call to a php sript with the argument.

**Step 3** backend php should return a json object array with desird question and option.

**Step 4**:js function should now arrange to print the return value accordingly

Comment: ive tried alot of javascript and ajax codes. i need the code

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN TRY THIS OUT:
php code can be:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";

        if ($result = $conn->query($sql)){
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
             <div id="question_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class='question'>
                    <h2><?php echo $row['id'];?></h2> 
                    <input type="radio" class="quiz-radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer1'];?>"><?php echo $row['answer1'];?>
                    <input type="radio" class="quiz-radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer2'];?>"><?php echo $row['answer2'];?>
                    <input type="radio" class="quiz-radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer3'];?>"><?php echo $row['answer3'];?>
                    <input type="radio" class="quiz-radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer4'];?>"><?php echo $row['answer4'];?>
            </div>       

           <?php }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
```

js code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.question').hide();
jQuery('.question').first().show();
    jQuery('.quiz-radio').change(function(){
        console.log(jQuery(this).val());//display answer
        var current=jQuery(this).closest('.question');
        current.hide();
        current.next().show();
    });
});
```

> NOTE: you need to call the js file in the .php or .phtml file.
>    I executed this code in my system , where all my questions and answers are in the database . i have stored them in a php variable.

Comment: But u can enclose each question with its radio group in a single div , and i think thats the easiest way you can show and hide them

Comment: i have alot of questions in my database and both questions and answers are fetched from database. how can i create separate div for that?. its not posible

Comment: i mean to say u can open a div after your while statement and end that div before while ends ,its loop so obviously u dont have to enclose each of them

Comment: select * from questions LIMIT 0, 1 // index_from, amount ,this query helps me restrict the question from many to one. i want to know how to get the next question from database when the button is clicked

Comment: PHP is executed before browser constructs a DOM tree or even dom elements, you should store each row in a php variable.then loop through them as the radio gets clicked. 
i dont think so there's any way to control php with javascript events

Comment: the code u gave has some error" Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array in C:\xamppp\htdocs\clickgoedit\public\index.php on line 116"

Comment: I have a edited the php code here, you can put this doirectly after u complete your connection

Comment: Undefined variable: conn in "if ($result = $conn->query($sql)){"

Comment: $conn is my php object on which i have used to make a connection, u have to use your objects name,

Comment: am a starter in sql. what should i use there. my database name is quiz and table name is questions

Comment: u have to use $con if u did a connection and assigned it to $con

Comment: If this worked for you, u can accept this answer.
refer : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers